# Spring cloud stream - RabbitMQ configuration

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am learning RabbitMq using spring cloud stream java. Having doubts in the mq configuration.

As per documents -
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.>channelName>.destination=dest1

I am using below configuration and it's working-

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=dest1

But if I mention my channel name in place of input like below, it's not working -
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myChannel.destination=dest1

In my class -
@INPUT('myChannel')

My doubt is why is it not working when I mention the channelName given in class and

But it is working when I give default as .input.  ..?

**UPDATE**

MyInterface.java

```
String CHANNEL = myChannel;
@INPUT(CHANNEL )
SubscribableChannel subs();
```

MyListener.java

```
@StreamListener(MyInterface.CHANNEL)
public void queueMsg(String str) {
   System.out.println("Str msg = "+str);
}
```

application.prop

```
#Below property working fine
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=dest1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=rabbit


#Below property NOT working 
#spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myChannel.destination=dest1
#spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myChannel.binder=rabbit
```

Comment: You need to show your listener and interface.

Answer (score 0):

The channel name is the binding name `input` in this case.

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.**input**.destination=dest1

For RabbitMQ, the destination is the exchange name that we will publish to.

Use `@Input("input")`.

Or

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.**myChannel**.destination=dest1

If it's not working, you need to show your listener and interface.

Comment: Describe "not working" in more detail. Exactly what is "not working"? Do you have a queue bound to the exchange `myChannel` (the first is sending to an exchange `input` the second is sending to an exchange `myChannel`.

Comment: im not sure, how to check the queue bounding. could you please help me over that. How to check the queue boundings
sry for inconvenience.

Comment: You can look at the exchanges on the rabbitmq management console and see all the bindings. Or, on the command line with `rabbitmqadmin list bindings`.

Comment: Got resolved. I checked the rabbitMQ UI console, for some reason binding was not getting updated if I redeploy my project. So I completely deleted the project from server and cleared everything, created new rabbitMQ and redeploy project. After that it's working. Thanks Gary.